# Writing a global sniffer

Tags: c, winsock

this is an example of the code I using to capture all the traffic passing by my network card. Unfortunately not all traffic is captured. For example, I don't see the HTTP traffic that should be encrypted and the related images that are downloaded when looking at a site's page. I thought of this code as a recorder that stores all the bits that pass from the network card, but that's not the case: are there any limitations imposed by Windows that I don't know?

Thank you

```
void main()
{
    int iResult = 0, in=0;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET s;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf(L"WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }
    
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
    
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf(L"socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());        
        return;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    struct hostent *local;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    char hostname[100];

    iResult = gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
    local=gethostbyname(hostname);
    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    memcpy(&dest.sin_addr.s_addr,local->h_addr_list[in],sizeof(dest.sin_addr.s_addr));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = 0;

    iResult = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof (dest));
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        //...
        return;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Enable this socket with the power to sniff : SIO_RCVALL is the key Receive ALL ;)
    int j=1;
    if(WSAIoctl(s, SIO_RCVALL, &j, sizeof(j), 0, 0, (LPDWORD)&in ,0 ,0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //......
        return;
    }

    char *Buffer = (char *)malloc(65535);

    while(!Terminated)
    {
        iResult = recvfrom(s, Buffer, 65535, 0, 0, 0);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            sprintf(L"recvfrom failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            iphdr = (IPV4_HDR *)Buffer;
            
            fwrite(Buffer,iResult,1,fp);    // for example
        }
    }

    free(Buffer);
    
    iResult = closesocket(s);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //.....
        return;
    }

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: You are running your program with administrator rights (they are required for `SIO_RCVALL`)? Possibly, your web browser uses IPv6 to connect to some server; in this case you need two raw sockets: One `AF_INET` socket for sniffing IPv4 connections and one `AF_INET6` socket for sniffing IPv6 connections.

Comment: @MartinRosenau:yes, I run the program as an Administrator.
Now I try AF_INET6.
Thank you.

Comment: after modifying the code to connect ipv6, i discovered that ipv6 is not implemented in my connection, is it the fault of the provider and its devices? Unfortunately I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: There are connections that don't support IPv6. In this case, you don't need the `AF_INET6` socket because there are no IPv6 packets that you could sniff...

Comment: I discovered that there are limitations with raw sockets on microsoft operating systems from XP onwards, I think for security problems.

Comment: https://www.winpcap.org/